# Is there any declare for toggle() that if its open do this, closed to that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing some jquery stuff with `toggle()`, I'm doing different actions depending on if the current `div` is closing or showing, i know i can easy check if a div `hasClass()` or `is(':visible')` for what i want to do, but I'm  thinking maybe there is somehow that i can reduce the amount of code or just do it more efficient? like declare the toggle() with two functions that this is for when its showing and this is for when its closing, is this possible?

hope you get what i mean?

like this, or check a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqFhe/1/)

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function() {
    $('#contain').toogle('blind', 300, function (){
        alert('open');
    }, function (){
        alert('close');          
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `toggle()` only supports one callback. Your strategy is sound, though: you can check if the element `is(":visible")` in the callback and act accordingly.

Comment: Since you're looking for a way to reduce the amount of code, you might be able to do that by abstracting this behavior into a custom [jQuery plugin function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started) that you can reuse.

Comment: You are mixing toggle effect method and toggle event handler.

Comment: i've edited your fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/QqFhe/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/QqFhe/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a small jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myToggle = function(duration, cbShow, cbHide){
        this.each(function(){
            $(this).toggle(duration, $(this).is(":visible") ? cbHide : cbShow);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage exactly as you suggested in your question; I just left out the easing method...

[**Demo (JSFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/QqFhe/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var container = $('.container');
$('.button').click(function() {
  container.toggle(function() {
    alert(container.is(':visible') ? 'open': 'close');
  });
});
```